# Looping through a MySQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some code that queries my MySQL database. My problem is, if checks only the first row of my table. I know I need to have a for loop, but what I tried out does not work. The working code that checks only the first line is

```
public function checkPart($aid, $uname) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM part WHERE aid = '$aid'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $aiddb = $result['aid'];
            $unamedb = $result['uname'];

            if ($unamedb == $uname) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return mysql_error();
        }

}
```

What I tried is this:

```
public function checkPart($aid, $uname) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM part WHERE aid = '$aid'") or die(mysql_error());
    // check for result 
    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    for($x=1; $x<= $no_of_rows;$x++){
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $aiddb = $result['aid'];
            $unamedb = $result['uname'];

            if ($unamedb == $uname) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return mysql_error();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with correcting my code? I am a beginner so pardon me if the question is too simple.

Comment: You can use a while loop. Also, sometime around the last ice age, PHP's MySQL API became deprecated

Comment: @Strawberry, how? I don't know how to do. That's my problem

Comment: Can I ask what are you trying to accomplish? username exists in a table? You may not need to loop, but instead have a single query to check if it exists in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de facto way to do this is with a while loop:

```
$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($no_of_rows == 0) {
    return mysql_error();
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // ... use $row['aid'], $row['uname'], etc.
    }
}
```

Your own code may work, but you were overwriting `$result`:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

So, after one iteration of the loop, you had lost the result of the query.

Note: `mysql_*` functions [are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) due to security issues, you are advised to learn `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: I added `$aiddb = $result['aid'];
    $unamedb = $result['uname'];

    if ($unamedb == $uname) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
    }` inside the while loop. Now I only get the details of the last row. First one is ignored

Comment: @YohanBlake you're not ordering your query, so the order is probably randomized - so maybe you don't get the last row. In any case, when you use `return`, you will exit from the function, so indeed, the rest of the loop is not executed. If you want to return all results, you have to store them temporarily in an array and at the end of the function, after the while loop, return that array. Lastly, with my code example, you have to use `$row['aid']`, not `$result['aid']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function checkPart($aid, $uname) 
{
        // It's think it's better to distinct the query itself
        // Therefore u can re-use the code easily.

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM part WHERE aid = \"$aid\"";
       $result = mysql_query($sql);

       // Catch errors
       if (!$result) 
       {
           die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
       }

       // If i'm correct u're using for just to loop the result
       // of fetch_array
      // It's easier like in the example in the man to do

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
           // Didn't see where this variable is used but u'll use later i suppose

           $aiddb = $row['aid'];
           $unamedb = $row['uname'];

           if ($unamedb == $uname) 
           {
               // user authentication details are correct
               return $result;
           }
           else
              echo 'User not found \n';
    }
} // checkPart()
```

I'm pretty new to coding aswell but I suggest u to read the man a lot. It's really Helped me. Btw u should take a look at PDO for database query.

Source :

[PHP.net fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

[PDO introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)